# Im getting 2 errors i cant resolve; 1 invalid use of member (did you forget the '&' ?) and recipe for target 'main.o' failed

Tags: c++

When I compile the code I get an error on **line 47**:

`[Error] invalid use of member (did you forget the '&' ?)`

I’m unsure why, since I’m trying add score to the `total_score`.

The second issue is an error saying recipe for target 'main.o' failed. This is not in my code but brings up a new tab labeled makefile.win

here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class Student
{

   public:
      void student_name();
      void quiz_score();
      void total_score();
      void average_score();

   private:
      int the_number_of_quizs;
      int sum_of_scores;
      double score_average;
};

void Student::student_name()
{
   string name;
   cout << "Please enter your name" << endl;
   cin >> name;
   cout << endl;
}

void Student::quiz_score()
{
   cout << "What was your score on the quiz?: " << endl;
   int score;
   cin >> score;
   total_score += score;
   the_number_of_quizs++;
}

void Student:: average_score() 
{ 
   score_average= sum_of_scores/ the_number_of_quizs;
}

void Student:: total_score()
{
   cout << "Total score: " << sum_of_scores << endl;
}

int main ()
{
   Student student1;
   student1.quiz_score();
   student1.student_name();
   student1.total_score();
   student1.average_score();

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: total_score should be sum_of_scores.

Comment: you do realize there are no line numbers here.

Answer (score 2):

you have this `void total_score()`

**total_score** is a  function returning void, that is why the following is invalid:

```
total_score += score;
```

I suspect you meant to use:

```
sum_of_scores += score;
```

Answer (score 0):

If at all I understand what you were tryna do, then it seems your major problem was coming from the line you had:

```
total_score += score;
```

Running that will flag you this:

```
main.cpp:38:9: error: invalid use of member function ‘void Student::total_score()’ (did you forget the ‘()’ ?)
         total_score += score;
         ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

It seems you wanna add the previous score of the student to the current score he/she has. If my assumptions were right, then I think `total_score` shouldn't be what you need, you will need `sum_of_scores`

This should end you up with the below as your new code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>


using namespace std;

class Student
    {

    public:
    void student_name();
    void quiz_score();
    void total_score();
    void average_score();

    private:
    int the_number_of_quizs;
    int sum_of_scores;
    double score_average;


    };
void Student::student_name()
    {
        string name;
        cout << "Please enter your name" << endl;
        cin >> name;
        cout << endl;
    }

void Student::quiz_score()
    {
        cout << "What was your score on the quiz?: " << endl;
        int score;
        cin >> score;
        sum_of_scores += score; //This is where you're correction is.
        the_number_of_quizs++;



    }

void Student:: average_score() 
    { 
    score_average= sum_of_scores/ the_number_of_quizs;

    }


void Student:: total_score()
    {

        cout << "Total score: " << sum_of_scores << endl;
    }



int main ()
{
    Student student1;
    student1.quiz_score();
    student1.student_name();
    student1.total_score();
    student1.average_score();

    return 0;


}
```

And when you run that, you should be able to get this: [image: Result]